# Selenium Webdriver Tutorial

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am interested in learning Selenium Webdriver.
Can anyone please let me know where I can find the selenium tutorials?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SQA. Could you let us know where you've looked so far and why those tutorials didn't work for you? Right now this question is something a simple web search would answer.

Comment: Just googling it will have much reputed sites to look in for.

Comment: It's been a while since this was posted, so I would imagine that if you're still on the road of learning Selenium that you've made great leaps by now. If you have further specific problems with Selenium, go ahead and ask those on a new question, we'll be happy to help you through it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To learn basics of Selenium, I must recommend you to go through below video tutorials. These are small and very informative:

http://www.guru99.com/selenium-tutorial.html

Also I have found below these [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFHX3LQXu_8&list=PLIMVrgO3pPB521LWAu8PXe8iB-LSE4LKo) tutorials very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Before starting with selenium, brushup your skills on Java and HTML which requires you for element identification.

Please refer the below link which provides you tutorials for not only selenium webdriver, it also provides for TestNG, JUnit, ANT ,Maven and other Report Generation tools.

http://seleniumeasy.com